# Using the original python packages instead of the jython packages

Tags: java, python, jython

I am trying to create a hybrid application with python back-end and java GUI and for that purpose I am using jython to access the data from the GUI. 
I wrote code using a standard Python 3.7.4 virtual environment and it worked "perfectly". But when I try to run the same code on jython it doesn't work so it seems that in jython some packages like **threading** are overwritten with java functionality.

My question is how can I use the **threading** package for example from python but in jython environment?

Here is the error:

> Exception in thread Thread-1:Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/home/dexxrey/jython2.7.0/Lib/threading.py", line 222, in _Thread__bootstrap
>       self.run()
>    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)

Answer (score 1):

Since you have already decoupled the application i.e using python for backend and java for GUI, why not stick to that and build in a communication layer between the backend and frontend, this layer could either be REST or any Messaging framework.

Comment: This also came up to my mind and it is still a viable option. The back-end can communicate with the front-end with xmls, but then I have to do listeners in both layers which listens for file changes, because there is no other way to invoke action from one layer to another. This is why i want to avoid this.

Comment: Well, I don't know you app requirement and scope, but listeners is not how I would proposed u communicate with, rather let the backend do the listening and expose the action of the listener via an API endpoint

Answer (score 1):

I think one issue you might be facing is that you are running on Jython 2.7.0 (~Python 2.7 compatible) but your code is written for CPython 3.7.4. So you might be facing Python 2 vs 3 issues.

The threading module in Jython is indeed different from CPython i.e. it is making use of JVM threading. However the intension is to be API compatible with Python 2.7 code so if it doesn't run that should be considered a bug.

My first suggestion would be try Jython 2.7.1 it contains many fixes over 2.7.0 https://www.jython.org/download however I suspect it still might not work. Check if your code runs on CPython 2.7 https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2716/ if it does then that sounds like a Jython bug. Open a ticket with details to reproduce at https://bugs.jython.org/